# React: двойная отрисовка

Tags: javascript, reactjs, компоненты

написал простой проект на React, главный компонент ничего не делает, отрисовывает пустой блок:

```
class AppMain extends React.Component {
    render() {
        console.log("MAIN");
        return <></>
    }
}

...

const root = createRoot(document.getElementById("root") as HTMLElement);
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <AppMain />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

вижу, что происходит двойной вызов:

```
MAIN
VM485:236 MAIN
```

Тоже самое уже в нормальном проекте - двойной вызов компонент.
С чем это связано и как с этим бороться (если конечно это не какое-то стандартное поведение)?

Comment: Уберите `<React.StrictMode>`. И будет вам счастье

Comment: @Randall, а почему вообще это возникает? Опять же польза в StrictMode есть? У меня то это в коде "из коробки" просто - что конструктор приложения первоначально сделал, то и стоит

Comment: Конечно есть польза. Строгий режим активирует дополнительные проверки и предупреждения для своих потомков.

Comment: если вещь полезная, то лучше же оставить - но почему двойной вызов?

Comment: Это одна из проверок. По идее компонент не должен зависеть от того сколько раз его рендерили.

Comment: Рекомендую читать документацию https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html